# How do I download, modify, then install a debian package?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, pagespeed

I'd like to run nginx on a jessie server with the pagespeed module compiled into nginx.

Instead of starting from scratch for my build script, I'd like to add the pagespeed module to the build script that is run when I execute `apt-get install nginx`. Then compile and set up nginx from this modified script.

But, I have no idea how to get the 'source code' or what the right technical terms to search for are for completing this.

Comment: This is a cross-site dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the source package:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
```

Get the build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get source --compile <package>
```

You can  fix a package bug by:

```
 dpatch-edit-patch somebug.dpatch
```

And build the modified package:

```
 debuild -b -uc -us
```

Installing the modified package:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../package_<your arch>.deb
```

Have a look at [Debian Building Tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this was super helpful. The one item I'd add that took me a little bit of time to sort out is that I also needed to add the line `deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main` to my apt-get sources.